# VisualStudio GIT detected changes which are already commited

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I have an abstract problem, it's just visual nothing too disturbing.

However i do apologise for my bad english in this matter.

-

I'm using GitHub for Windows as GitCommit, however even if i commit a changed file using GitHub, visual studio still says that the file was changed.

Some pictures regarding Visual Studio
[image: Visual Studio1]
[image: Visual Studio commit-in interface]

However if i commit the changes AGAIN in the VS Interface, this is the result:

[image: Visual Studio CommitEntry]

He's practically re-commiting everything i already did using GitHub.

Why these 2 Softwares aren't syncronised or something?

Answer (score 0):

I already get some issues like yours... In my case the reason were some version incompatibility. Try to check out if the  VS plugin is compatible with the version of GitHub for windows.